# State persistence between sessions, with nextjs and mobx

Tags: next.js, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-persist

Has anybody else managed to get state persistence between sessions, with nextjs and mobx?

I keep running into issues with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save it in localStorage, and initialize state with it :

example :

```
const [state, setState] = useState(localStorage.getItem(‘state’));
```

Comment: Do you have an example of that?

Comment: i gave you example, what kind of  example ?

Comment: I don't understand how this would integrate with mobx. Some example of the config?

Comment: show the state management code